# Parameter from Notification Dictionary Any or Bool?

Tags: swift, dictionary, boolean

I'm confused because I'm passing a parameter by `Notification` between two ViewControllers. I than try to use the parameter passed as `Bool` to go forward:

```
func doWhenParameterSelected(notification: Notification) {

    let status = notification.userInfo!["key0"]!
     print(type(of:status)) //is "Bool" in Console
     print(status) // value is "true" or "false" in Console

    if status {... // error occurs "'Any' is not convertible to 'Bool'"
```

I always get the error message `'Any' is not convertible to 'Bool'`.

So, why is `status` `Any` when `type(of: status))` is `Bool` in Console. If `Any` type how can I use `status` as `Bool` type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `userInfo` parameter is defined as `[AnyHashable : Any]` (an unspecified `Dictionary`) regardless what you are sending.

If you are responsible for the notification and the `userInfo` parameter never changes just forced cast the value to `Bool`

```
let status = notification.userInfo!["key0"] as! Bool
```

Answer (score 2):

You must cast it to Bool before using it as a condition.

```
func doWhenParameterSelected(notification: Notification) {

    guard notification.userInfo?["key0"] as? Bool ?? false else {
        // could not cast to Bool or it was false
        return
    }

    // ...
}
```

***OR***

```
func doWhenParameterSelected(notification: Notification) {

    if notification.userInfo?["key0"] as? Bool ?? false {
        // ...
    } else {
        // could not cast to Bool or it was false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast it as `Bool`:

```
let status = notification.userInfo!["key0"] as? Bool ?? false
```

Comment: could you do it in a single step`if  let status = notification.userInfo!["key0"] as? Bool'

Comment: Yes question updated and thanks for the comment. @Russell